# How do I access content from JSON string?

Tags: node.js, json, angularjs, express, object

I am receiving a JSON object from the backend now I just want "result" array only in my template variable in my angular application from it.

```
{
"result":[
{"name":"Sunil Sahu",
"mobile":"1234567890",
"email":"abc@gmail.com",
"location":"Mumbai",
"Age":"19"
}
],
"status":200
}
```

Comment: Please add the code where you recieve the data. Most importantly code where is a variable which holds the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```js
variable_name["result"].
```

Comment: store the json object in a variable. let's say body = JSON object. now if the JSON object has 'result', then body['result'] should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

var data = response from the backend

var result = data.result;

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = '{"result":[{"name":"Sunil Sahu","mobile":"1234567890","email":"abc@gmail.com","location":"Mumbai","Age":"19"}],"stats":200}';
```

If your $var is string, you need to turn it to "array" or "object" by json_decode() function

object:

```
$var_object = json_decode($var);       //this will get an object
$result = $var_object->result;         //$result is what you want to get
```

array:

```
$var_array  = json_decode($var, true); //this will get an array
$result     = $var_array['result'];    //$result is what you want to get
```

Else if $var is object, direct use

```
$result = $var->result; //$result is what you want to get
```

Answer (score 0):

As result is an array of objects, you can either use any loop to extract key value pair or you can directly access the array using index value.

```
var results = data["result"] // this would return an array

angular.forEach(results, function(value, key) {
    //access key value pair 
  });
```

For accessing results in HTML, *ng-repeat* directive can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Your question didn't explain further, but in the simple way try this :

```js
const stringJson = `{
"result":[
{"name":"Sunil Sahu",
"mobile":"1234567890",
"email":"abc@gmail.com",
"location":"Mumbai",
"Age":"19"
}
],
"status":200
}`

const obJson = JSON.parse(stringJson);
console.log(obJson.result);
```